# Installing a specific version of gcc-5 (gcc 5.4.0)

Tags: apt, gcc

There are many questions here asking how to install gcc 5.4.0. The ones that I have found have answers saying to just `sudo apt install gcc-5` and then run the appropriate update-alternatives. That works, however gcc-5 installs gcc 5.5, and I need to install gcc 5.4.0.

Is there a way to specify to apt a particular version?